# user->save() is not creating a new record in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks, controller

I am trying to save details of a user after saving the values in a form. I have written a controller to post the user details and save it in the database, but the user->save() seems to be not working for me.

```
public function postAddBusiness()
{
    $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'same:password_confirm',
    'name' => 'required',
    'business-type' => 'required'
    );
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('business/add')->withErrors($validation)->withInput(); 
    }
    $user = new User;
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    if (Input::get('password')) 
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    }
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->type = Input::get('business-type');
    //$he= $user->save();
    if ($user->save())
    {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('notify','Information updated');
    }
        print_r($user);
```

}

While I return the array $user, I am getting the values I entered in the form.

```
User Object ( [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [email] => b1@b.com [password] => $2y$10$KWGRMooHxavSbnhcGKqnNe19hstF44lPjVkseX5BwJ.HYUzRzzg7m [name] => B1 [type] => plumber ) [original:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => [errors] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [username] => Array ( [0] => The username field is required. ) [password_confirmation] => Array ( [0] => Wrong confirmation code. ) ) [format:protected] => :message ) )
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $user->type = Input::get('business-type'); May be you need to change $user->business-type

Comment: It seems that your model also has additional validation rules, it says 'Username field is required' and 'password_confirmation field is required' in the output. Are you by any chance using Ardent?

Comment: I am using confide, but shouldn't it save in db even if I don't have a password_confirmation?

Comment: Confide by default (in its `ConfideUser` trait) has its own built-in validation which requires `username` and `password_confirmation` (though it unsets password_confirmation right before saving it, but still try to validate its existence). Follow this link to build your own validation: https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/#custom-user-validation

Comment: I have fixed it, I changed the table in Business model and changed $user->type to $user->business-type.

Thanks